# Send a broadcast POP-UP Message to All the Connected Clients

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, signalr

I am building(still learning) a web application in ASP.NET WebForms with C#.We have a Centralized Database and all Clients are connected to the Database through a same static IP.Each of the Clients have their own
Unique Office ID.We have 16 Offices each having their own office ID.Every Day we update new features with new build.Instead of sending chat message
to individual client about the new changes/updates/features, can we make it send as a broadcast message like from all the offices i have mentioned
there is a corporate office with OfficeId=14.So the moment the User from other office Logs in, he/she should see a pop-up notification message
about the changes.Is it possible to make  say a form to enter the details about the changes and the moment the user from the corporte office saves it, it shows in the index page of 
all the clients?

I did a lot of research on this, but couldnt get a solid explanation.This might be a duplicate or lame question for all the experts out here,please
bear with me.

Answer (score 2):

Check this link [ASP.Net SignalR: Building a Simple Real-Time Chat Application](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/8c19e8/asp-net-signalr-building-a-simple-real-time-chat-applicatio/)

from the ChatHub class and Use following Code.

```
 public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> dic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }



    public void Notify(string name, string id)
    {
        if (dic.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            Clients.Caller.differentName();
        }
        else
        {
            dic.TryAdd(name, id);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> entry in dic)
            {
                Clients.Caller.online(entry.Key);
            }
            Clients.Others.enters(name);
        }
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        var name = dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == Context.ConnectionId.ToString());
        string s;
        dic.TryRemove(name.Key, out s);
        return Clients.All.disconnected(name.Key);
    }

}
```

And in HTML + javascript

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

          $(function () {
              showModalUserNickName();
          });

          function showModalUserNickName() {
              $("#dialog").dialog({
                  modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                      Ok: function () {
                          $(this).dialog("close");
                          startChartHub();
                      }
                  }
              });
          }

          function startChartHub() {
              var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

              // Get the user name.
              $('#nickname').val($('#nick').val());
              chat.client.differentName = function (name) {
                  showModalUserNickName();
                  return false;
                  // Prompts for different user name
                  $('#nickname').val($('#nick').val());
                  chat.server.notify($('#nickname').val(), $.connection.hub.id);
              };

              chat.client.online = function (name) {
                  // Update list of users
                  if (name == $('#nickname').val())
                      $('#onlineusers').append('<div class="border" style="color:green">You: ' + name + '</div>');
                  else {
                      $('#onlineusers').append('<div class="border">' + name + '</div>');
                  }
              };

              chat.client.enters = function (name) {
                  $('#chatlog').append('<div style="font-style:italic;"><i>' + name + ' joins the conversation</i></div>');
                  $('#onlineusers').append('<div class="border">' + name + '</div>');
              };
              // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast chat messages.
              chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                  //Interpret smileys
                  message = message.replace(":)", "<img src=\"/images/smile.gif\" class=\"smileys\" />");
                  message = message.replace("lol", "<img src=\"/images/laugh.gif\" class=\"smileys\" />");
                  message = message.replace(":o", "<img src=\"/images/cool.gif\" class=\"smileys\" />");

                  //display the message
                  $('#chatlog').append('<div class="border"><span style="color:red">' + name + '</span>: ' + message + '</div>');
              };

              chat.client.disconnected = function (name) {
                  //Calls when someone leaves the page
                  $('#chatlog').append('<div style="font-style:italic;"><i>' + name + ' leaves the conversation</i></div>');
                  $('#onlineusers div').remove(":contains('" + name + "')");
              }

              // Start the connection.
              $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                  //Calls the notify method of the server
                  chat.server.notify($('#nickname').val(), $.connection.hub.id);

                  $('#btnsend').click(function () {

                          // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                          chat.server.send($('#nickname').val(), $('#message').val());

                      // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                      $('#message').val('').focus();
                  });

              });
          }

        </script>
<div id="container">
<input type="hidden" id="nickname" />
<div id="chatlog"></div>
<div id="onlineusers">
    <b>Online Users</b>
</div>
<div id="chatarea">
    <div class="messagelog">
        <textarea spellcheck="true" id="message" class="messagebox"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="actionpane">
        <input type="button" id="btnsend" value="Send" />
    </div>
    <div class="actionpane">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="dialog" title="Enter your name to start a chat.">
    <input type="text" id="nick" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is this for Broadcast Message Sir?

Comment: It will broadcast to all who is connected...to you app. Just try it , if it is not working then let me know.

Comment: OK sir i am giving it a try..will let you know

Comment: Didnt Work Sir.The Send button isnt firing

Comment: Have you add this follwing line to your code
@section scripts{
             @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js")
             @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.1.min.js")
             @Scripts.Render("/signalr/hubs")
}

Comment: Yes i did add this line..I did a different way sir..the button is fired but the notification is not showing up across the page

Comment: @OLDMONK I had also tried the same can you suggest whether the problem is solved its not working here